# C pointer chain call

Tags: c, pointers

I want to use a pointer that refereed to a heap memory (malloc function allocated).I have to free the memory.

```c
    for (int i = 0;i < yk->m;i++){
        Coords range = {0,-1};
        Coords ykc = {0,i};
        set_m(yk,ykc,sum_i(dot_times_m(yv,matrix_pow(xv,i)),0,range));
    }
```

as the above code , dot_times_m is a function that return a pointer allocated by malloc.but due to no variable to refereed to the pointer,I can't free it.

Comment: Why don't you extract the function call and assign the value to a pointer, use that pointer in this call and later free it? What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: because the result of dot_times_m only use once , I think it is not need to extract the function call

Comment: "I think it is not need to extract the function call". Clearly it is needed for the very reason that you have asked this question - to be able to free the returned pointer.

Comment: Chaining calls just for the sake of it isn't really being clever. Just don't chain the calls.

Comment: If you need to reference the pointer after passing it as an argument, then you must assign it to a variable.

Comment: **You do not need it only once because you need it the second time to pass as an argument to `free`.** Here, I solved the dilemma for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should extract that function call and then assign the result to a pointer of the right type. Use that pointer in the later function call and free it. You need the pointer twice anyway - first for passing to the function and second to pass to `free()`.

Example:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < yk->m; i++ )
{
    Coords range = {0,-1};
    Coords ykc = {0,i};

    p = dot_times_m( yv, matrix_pow(xv, i) );   // assign the result to p
    set_m( yk, ykc, sum_i(p, 0, range) );       // use p in this call
    free( p );                                  // free p after use
}
```

Another way could be to directly use this pointer assignment in the chaining call and later free the pointer like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < yk->m; i++ )
{
    Coords range = {0,-1};
    Coords ykc = {0,i};

    set_m( yk, ykc, sum_i( p = dot_times_m( yv, matrix_pow(xv, i) ), 0, range) );
    //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    free( p );
}
```

But, in this case, you would be sacrificing the readability!